# How do I know what to write when i map a fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Having some trouble with this .map function saying that it's not a function.

What it's supposed to do is get the data based on the URL and then insert it into a mapped component.

Here is the component itself:

```
export default function Trainers() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const { id } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/trainers/${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));
    
    console.log(data);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Pos>
        <SmallHeadline>
          <Cap>Trainer</Cap>
        </SmallHeadline>
      </Pos>
      {data.data.map((course, key) => {
        return (
          <TrainerCard key={key}>
            <TrainerImgCon
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${course.asset.url})` }}
            ></TrainerImgCon>
            <TrainerTxt>{course.trainerName}</TrainerTxt>
          </TrainerCard>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The API that it's taking the data from looks like this:
[fetched data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2i8R.png)

Appreciate any insight on this

Comment: I do get console logged data but the data.data.map doesn't seem to be the right move

Comment: that only stopped the error from showing. How do I know what the data is called according to the image that I linked to this post? if it's not data.data but data.somethinghere

Comment: Why not just ‘data.map’ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that the initial state has nothing that is mappable

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

and on the initial render you are expecting at least a `data.data` to exist

```
{data.data.map((course, key) => {
  return (
    <TrainerCard key={key}>
      <TrainerImgCon
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${course.asset.url})` }}
      ></TrainerImgCon>
      <TrainerTxt>{course.trainerName}</TrainerTxt>
    </TrainerCard>
  );
})}
```

## Solution

I suggest providing valid initial state

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });
```

Or use Optional Chaining or some other null check on the mapping

```
{data.data?.map((course, key) => {
  return (
    <TrainerCard key={key}>
      <TrainerImgCon
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${course.asset.url})` }}
      ></TrainerImgCon>
      <TrainerTxt>{course.trainerName}</TrainerTxt>
    </TrainerCard>
  );
})}
```

From what I can tell of your example response value though, perhaps there is no nested `data` property, and it also seems to be an object, not an array, so there may not be anything to map. The empty object (`{}`) `data` state is fine.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

...

return (
  <div>
    <Pos>
      <SmallHeadline>
        <Cap>Trainer</Cap>
      </SmallHeadline>
    </Pos>
    <TrainerCard key={key}>
      <TrainerImgCon
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${course.asset.url})` }}
      />
      <TrainerTxt>{data.trainerName}</TrainerTxt>
    </TrainerCard>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @ClunkyKong The state is still empty after updating it? How is that even possible? Can you share how you are validating the state update, and also post that example response value as a text snippet instead of an image?

Comment: Thank you I actually don't know why I was trying to map this anyway. This helped a bunch!!

Comment: @ClunkyKong No worries. So this answer got you straightened out and working again, or do you still need assistance with the state and rendering?

Comment: This answer got it straightened out, for now, appreciate it

Comment: @ClunkyKong Great! Glad to help. Cheers.